# How to fetch list of users with permission 'x' in zizaco entrust laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, entrust

I wanted to show list of users those are having permission 'x'.  I am using zizaco/entrust plugin in laravel 5.1 for managing roles/permissions. I have setup roles and permissions already. Previously i was working with roles but change of specs i need it by permissions wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas()`:

```
$permissionName = 'x';

$userList = User::whereHas('roles.perms', function($query) use ($permissionName) {
    $query->whereName($permissionName);
})->get();

dd($userList);
```